# Setting up probability problem picking marbles uniformly from two bags

Tags: probability

Two bags initially contain $N$ marbles each. A marble is removed from one or the other bag, uniformly at random, until one of the bags is empty. At the time that one bag first becomes empty, what is the probability that the other bag contains exactly $k$ marbles?

My attempt: let the number of marbles in bag B after $t$ marbles have been drawn be $B_t$ and similarly the number of marbles in bag C after $t$ marbles have been drawn be $C_t$ (so then $B_t$+$C_t = t$). And then say something like the probability that the other bag contains $k$ marbles when the first bag becomes empty is equal to $P( B_t=k \cap C_t=0)+ P(B_t=0 \cap C_t=0)$. But this doesn't take into account that the bag with no marbles *just* became the bag with no marbles. And even after this, any hints on how to proceed?

Comment: Very similar: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1072363/selecting-n-matches-from-two-pockets

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Start from the probability that none of the marbles of the second bag are emptied...

Comment: That should give you very good intuition and also one can easily come up with an expression for any k working from that end.